# Как найти откуда вызывается scroll на сайте WP

Tags: javascript, wordpress, прокрутка, contact-form7

Есть проблемы с сайтом. Одна из них - это скролл пре переходе на новый шаг формы. Используется Contact Form 7 Multi-Step Forms, Contact Form 7.

Проблема в том, что иногда при переходе на следующий шаг формы, страница скроллится вниз, и это надо убрать.

Как можно найти, откуда вызывается скролл или как его запретить.

Важно, чт бы отключился скролл, который вызывается программно, но оставить скролл, который делает пользователь. Одним словом, `overflow: hidden` не подойдёт.

сайт: https://nova-partner.pl/registratsiya/?idb24=564

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте остановить выполнение

```
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    jQuery('html, body').stop();        
});
```